# Why I need to install Barcode Scanner to run this Android app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm new to android development. Currently developing basic android app for scanning qr code. For Demo I got source code. but when i tried to run Application. It require Barcode Scanner app to download from Playstore. Where i need to makes changes. Thank you

```
    public class AndroidBarcodeQrExample extends Activity {
    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set the main content layout of the Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //product barcode mode
    public void scanBar(View v) {
        try {
            //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //on catch, show the download dialog
            showDialog(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    //product qr code mode
    public void scanQR(View v) {
        try {
            //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //on catch, show the download dialog
            showDialog(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    //alert dialog for downloadDialog
    private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                }
            }
        });
        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });
        return downloadDialog.show();
    }

    //on ActivityResult method
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //get the extras that are returned from the intent
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);`

This above lines means, you're creating an intent for that specified action. Here the activity which is in the package of google's xzing app.
Hence the particular app is required. This is a power of android. You can easily invoke phone calls from your app by just specifying `ACTION_DIAL`, etc. Android will invoke the right app based on the content they handle (exposed by the Manifests).

Say you have two Dialer apps, you'll be provided the option to choose which.

In your case, since you use zxing, the particular app will be expected to be present. Remember you're not writing the whole bar code app, only invoking their actions.

Comment: means here I'm using source code with existing application.

Comment: This is not like using source code of another application in yours... more like a call to a library function.

Comment: I'm new to android development. Is it possible or easy to create my own rather to call. Though would be able to Scan directly. ? @padfoot

Comment: Yes. You'd be able to scan directly. But that's kind of too advanced for a beginner. You'd have to write your own zxing project. But that's not Android is about. It's about leveraging what it has to offer and build upon it.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and Support. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why I need to install Barcode Scanner to run this Android app

Your code is starting activities from the Barcode Scanner app. Hence, you need to have the Barcode Scanner app installed for those `startActivityForResult()` calls to work.

> Where i need to makes changes

You need to delete everything that you have in that code listing above. Then, you need to find [a barcode-scanning library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/11) that meets your needs.

Comment: Or he could just use the official [Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/).

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare My requirement is to only read qr code and print any message for learning purpose. any other suggestion would you like to give.

Comment: @Gergely Thank you so much. new concept for me to learn Mobile Vision API really interesting.

Comment: @RahulChhuttani Sure, no problem. Also, you can find [a sample project here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision).

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy thank you so much sir for your valuable reply :). I want to learn in depth.